# Remove all numbers followed by parenthese with Regex in R (use negative lookaheads?!)

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove all numbers that are immediately followed by a `)`.
My Strings look like this:

```
Gmünd 5) 6) 7)
Hermagor am See 3)
```

So I'd like to have the result:

```
Gmünd
Hermagor
```

I think the solution must involve negative lookaheads, but I am not really sure how to do that.

Comment: Sorry I have been unclear! This is what I meant. There might be spaces in the names, so trimming everything after the first white space does not work :/

Comment: What's the logic exactly? Why does the second line lost "am See" if you're just removing numbers and parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other digits in your strings a lookaround is not needed. If you do however, especially in the context of `(` and `)`, then lookaround, specifically negative lookbehind, is needed:

```
gsub("(?<!\\()\\s?\\d+\\)", "", strings, perl = TRUE)
[1] "Gmünd"            "Hermagor"         "Tegernsee (4)"    "Some (stuff) 444"
```

How this works:

- `(?<!\\()` negative lookbehind to assert that there is not a literal `(` immediately prior to ...
- `\\s?\\d+\\)` ... an optional space, followed by one or more digits, followed by a literal `)`

Data:

```
strings <- c("Gmünd 5) 6) 7)", "Hermagor 3)", "Tegernsee (4)", "Some (stuff) 444")
```

Comment: I think this is it!! Thank you so much!:) I know this is a little annoying, but could you maybe, very briefly explain, what the regex does ?

I see that the `(?<! ... )` part is the native lookbehind. I thought a lookahead might be necessary as my reasoning was: 

"Match everything that is not followed by any number with a parantheses right after".

So I do not get completely why a negative lookbehind is necessary here. Especially because there is nothing "after" the lookbehind. Like `(?<!a)b`.

Comment: Have edited answer to include a short explanation.